# Как сделать выбор персонажа?

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

У меня есть сцена  в которой можно выбрать персонажа, открываются они за рекорды. К примеру у тебя рекорд времени в игре 25 секунд и тогда откроется персонаж который открывается при 25 секундах. Пока персонаж не открыт, он имеет черный цвет (типа он еще не открыт) Происходит это так

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class IsEnabled : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int NeedToUnlock;
    public Color NewColor;
    SpriteRenderer SpriteR;
    public Sprite Pink_Monster;
    public SpriteRenderer PinkMonster;

    void Start()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SaveScore") < NeedToUnlock)
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.black;
        }

    }
```

В игре это выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Выбрать" и тогда в игре будет персонаж которого ты выбрал. К примеру я выбрал белого персонажа и в игре он появился (игра находиться на другой сцене). Объясните как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну например https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html , есть и другие решения, но их не помню уже

Comment: Не понимаю зачем мне нужен PlayerPrefs, да потом чтобы при выходе запоминало персонажа он понадобится, но сейчас мне нужно что при нажатии на кнопку на другой сцене загрузился другой префаб игрока (который ты выбрал). Чем он мне поможет ?

Comment: так а в чем проблема вместо 1 префаба, загрузить другой? гуглится же все https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html

Answer (score 0):

Для начала сделаем скрипт покупки.

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShopCar : MonoBehaviour
{

    private int numberPlayer; //Здесь хранится номер выбранного персонажа

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        numberPlayer = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player"); //Закладываем значение выбранного персонажа в PlayerPrefs
    }


    public void PlayerOwl() //каждый персонаж это отдельная функция чтобы можно было потом назначить их на кнопки
    {
        numberPlayer = 1; // Закладываем в переменную номер игрока
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player", numberPlayer); // Закладываем номер выбранного героя в PlayerPrefs, беря информацию из NumberPlayer
    }

    public void PlayerPink()
    {
        numberPlayer = 2;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player", numberPlayer);
    }
    public void PlayerDude()
    {
        numberPlayer = 3;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player", numberPlayer);
    }
    public void PlayerTiny()
    {
        numberPlayer = 4;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player", numberPlayer);
    }
    public void PlayerRed()
    {
        numberPlayer = 5;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player", numberPlayer);
    }
    public void PlayerYellow()
    {
        numberPlayer = 6;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player", numberPlayer);
    }

}
```

Потом делаем скрипт который будет находиться уже в самой игре (другая сцена)

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NumberCar : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int numberPlayer;

    public GameObject Player1;  // в каждую переменную ложим обьект который будет включаться при выборе в другом скрипте
    public GameObject Player2;
    public GameObject Player3;
    public GameObject Player4;
    public GameObject Player5;
    public GameObject Player6;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        numberPlayer = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player"); // получаем значение заложенное в PlayerPrefs, в приведущем скрипте
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(numberPlayer == 1)  //если значение в PlayerPrefs равно 1 (тоесть номер выбранного игрока 1) то включаем нужного игрока и отключаем остальных (на сцене уже стоят все игроки мы просто оставляем нужного
        {
            Player1.SetActive(true);
            Player2.SetActive(false);
            Player3.SetActive(false);
            Player4.SetActive(false);
            Player5.SetActive(false);
            Player6.SetActive(false);
        }

        if (numberPlayer == 2)
        {
            Player2.SetActive(true);
            Player1.SetActive(false);
            Player3.SetActive(false);
            Player4.SetActive(false);
            Player5.SetActive(false);
            Player6.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (numberPlayer == 3)
        {
            Player3.SetActive(true);
            Player1.SetActive(false);
            Player2.SetActive(false);
            Player4.SetActive(false);
            Player5.SetActive(false);
            Player6.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (numberPlayer == 4)
        {
            Player4.SetActive(true);
            Player1.SetActive(false);
            Player2.SetActive(false);
            Player3.SetActive(false);
            Player5.SetActive(false);
            Player6.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (numberPlayer == 5)
        {
            Player5.SetActive(true);
            Player1.SetActive(false);
            Player2.SetActive(false);
            Player3.SetActive(false);
            Player4.SetActive(false);
            Player6.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (numberPlayer == 6)
        {
            Player6.SetActive(true);
            Player1.SetActive(false);
            Player2.SetActive(false);
            Player3.SetActive(false);
            Player4.SetActive(false);
            Player5.SetActive(false);

        }
    }
}
```

Думаю можно было бы сделать проще, но меня устроил и такой вариант

Comment: Не очень хорошая реализация. Что будет с вашим кодом, если в будущем будут добавляться новые модельки? Правильно, он у вас разрастется до небывалых размеров

Comment: Согласен, но было ограничено время на раздумья, поэтому все так. Назвал бы это временным решением, но чувствую переделывать я его не буду :)